# Automating WPF application

Tags: wpf, selenium, automation, winappdriver

How can we automate wpf application because in my organization I am using the application which opens through the link which we paste in the browser we don't have EXE file for that so it's getting very tedious task to automate that using selenium, can anyone help if you have any idea

I want to automate application which opens through URL but it's not web application.

Comment: You've not explained whether this is rdp or xbap.  You should also be aware that asking questions which are opinion based is outside of stack overflow scope. Your question is almost certainly going to get closed for one or both those reasons.

Comment: I think your application is on "Click Once Deployment" . When we hit the URL then application download at your local from server and launch the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a WPF application there should be an exe.
May be your organization environment like when we paste URL on web it downloads the binaries(exe and dll's) at some location on your local machine and after that it is stating the WPF exe application.
In that case if you are a developer then when we build a project then all DLL and exe files found in bin\release folder. you have to pickup these local files for automation instead of deployed environment.

I have also faced same issue in my organization I build the WPF application on my local machine and I got the exe and DLL on it.

After that I did automation through WinAppDriver on it using Visual Studio with Unit Test Project.

I'll give you sample application and steps to do the WPF application automation.

Visit below GitHub project to achieve WPF application automation.
https://github.com/sandeepjadhav75502/AutomationScriptDesktopApp

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, you gave exact answer to my question, your answer is relevant to it.